# Using php to echo mysql query results in a tabular form

Tags: php, css

I have a small shopping cart I am writing, and currently am facing problems on how to display MySQL table results into a tabulated display. I have a code that does the whole database search and returns results, my problem is displaying the results like most shopping carts do.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve.

```
<table>

<tr>
<td>First mysql result row comes here</td>
<td>Second Mysql result row comes here</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>third mysql result row comes here</td>
<td>fourth Mysql result row comes here</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Note that it displays two `<td>` per line.

I am having a tough time trying to find this out. Could it be done using css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table>
<?php
$tr = false;

foreach( $results_from_database as $result ) {
    $tr = !$tr;

    if( $tr ) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    echo "<td>$result</td>";

    if( !$tr ) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}

// if there's odd amount of results, add an empty cell and close the tr tag
if( $tr ) {
    echo '<td></td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, yes, I used just a placeholder. You're supposed to replace it with the actual loop you use to go through the query results.